# How to call a JavaScript Function in Angular JS for a Carousel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, carousel

I am trying to call this JavaScript function in my Angular JS controller below.  The carousel buttons will not work like the example from this site http://www.bootply.com/1DtSbhZQtI.  Where is my error in the JavaScript? Thanks.

```
var myCarousel = function() {

$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel')};

myCarousel();
```

This is in order to run a thumbnail carousel on my html file, here is the code for the html.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="well">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

            <!-- Carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="images/StaticBarHeadcountHorizontal.png" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="images/StaticBarHeadcountVertical.png" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="images/StaticGroupedHeadcount.png" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="images/TrendBarHeadcount.png" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--/row-->
                </div>
                <!--/item-->
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/TrendDonutHeadcount.png" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/TrendLineHeadcount.png" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/TrendLinePercentofTotalHeadcount.png" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--/row-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/carousel-inner--> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
        </div>
        <!--/myCarousel-->
    </div>
    <!--/well-->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your controller? Because I haven't seen any trace of the controller in your html.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not related to angular, you just need to create the carousel with:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel();
```